# breaking ASP.NET long drop down list items into several lines

Tags: asp.net, combobox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to handle long text in dropdownlist control in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116395/how-to-handle-long-text-in-dropdownlist-control-in-asp-net)

I use VS2010, C# to develop ASP.NET web apps, sometimes my drop down contains long items which makes my combos big, is there any way that I can break large items into 2 (or more lines), so that my combo size is fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not make  it multiline. Instead you can make dropdown control fixed width and its dropdown(items) resize according to the content length

Try using CSS to add a fixed width to your dropdown, like:

```
select {width: 150px}
```

Whilst the dropdown itself will be of a fixed width and may not show all of the text, the option elements should expand to the width of the widest element.

Answer (score 1):

Default ComboBox behavior is a little bit too browser dependant. If you want to get an uniform and customized appearance you may use a jQuery plug-in (I assume you're using jQuery). You can *start* searching from [this list](http://www.designdim.com/2011/07/10-important-jquery-selectboxdropdown-plugins/).

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a cssClass for the Combo Box and then specify widths/heights for the `<li>` items.

Look at the different options for a ComboBox here: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx