# How can change width of dropdown list?

Tags: html, css, list, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a listbox and I want to decrease its width.

Here is my code:

```
<select name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr" style="width: 50px;">
  <option value="kg">Kg</option>
  <option value="gm">Gm</option>
  <option value="pound">Pound</option>
  <option value="MetricTon">Metric ton</option>
  <option value="litre">Litre</option>
  <option value="ounce">Ounce</option>
</select>
```

This code works on IE 6 but not in Mozilla Firefox (latest version). Can anybody please tell me how I can decrease the `width` of the dropdown list on Firefox?

Comment: It does work on Firefox 17.0.1.

Comment: Your code should work fine on ALL browsers..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set width of dropdown element in HTML select dropdown options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702186/set-width-of-dropdown-element-in-html-select-dropdown-options)

Comment: Why don't you change the width according to the width of the content? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091481/auto-resizing-the-select-element-according-to-selected-options-width/55343930#55343930

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<select name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr">
<option value="kg">Kg</option>
<option value="gm">Gm</option>
<option value="pound">Pound</option>
<option value="MetricTon">Metric ton</option>
<option value="litre">Litre</option>
<option value="ounce">Ounce</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
#wgtmsr{
 width:150px;   
}
```

If you want to change the width of the option you can do this in your css:

```
#wgtmsr option{
  width:150px;   
}
```

Maybe you have a conflict in your css rules that override the width of your select

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B3uSD/2/)

Comment: How is that any different than what the OP has?

Comment: Inline `style` definitions override every other styling (unless there's `!important`), so I don't think so. The OP's original code works fine even on Firefox 17.0.1.

Comment: @Abody97 maybe he has a conflict in his css

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. yes, the option width wasn't working but now using #wgtmsr option{width:50px;} its working(working by using class too).but before I put width style in every option tag as well as in select tag but that didn't work. yes may be that was overriden.

Comment: @Chris or unless you override them with `element[style]` in your css.

Comment: FYI This does not seem to make any difference on Chrome or IE11, it does however as the OP asked work for Firefox, I was looking for something a little more generic... :(

Comment: select {} never worked but using the name worked great!

Comment: It will not work if the option length is long.

Comment: I came here to find a solution if the option visible text content is way too large, assume "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" and the solution in the fiddle does absolutely nothing to prevent this.

Answer (score 11):

The dropdown width itself cannot be set. It's width depend on the option-values. See also here ( jsfiddle.net/LgS3C/ )

How the select box looks like is also depending on your browser.

You can build your own control or use Select2 
https://select2.org

Answer (score 9):

This:

`<select style="width: XXXpx;">`

XXX = Any Number

Works great in Google Chrome v70.0.3538.110

Answer (score 6):

Create a css and set the value `style="width:50px;"` in *css* code. Call the class of *CSS* in the drop down list. Then it will work.

Answer (score 6):

try the `!important` argument to make sure the CSS is not conflicting with any other styles you have specified. Also using a [reset.css](http://www.cssreset.com/) is good before you add your own styles.

```
select#wgmstr {
    max-width: 50px;
    min-width: 50px;
    width: 50px !important;
}
```

or

```
<select name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr" style="width: 50px !important; min-width: 50px; max-width: 50px;">
```

Comment: Did you actually try what you're suggesting? If you did, you might notice that the OP's original code already works.

Comment: that is why i am suggesting him to use the `!important` argument to make sure the code is not conflicting with other styles.

Comment: Adding `!important` is the only thing which worked for me. I always forget about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to control the width of the **list that drops down**, you can do it as follows.

**CSS**

```
#wgtmsr option {
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, at least not in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can style it on your CSS file using the id = #wgtmsr.

```
#wgtmsr{
  width: 50px;
}
```

And then remove the style element = 'style="width: 50px;"'