# Drop down list - Limit the width of all menu items

Tags: javascript, html, css, combobox

I want to limit the width of menu items shown in a drop down. For instance,
In this demo link http://jsfiddle.net/B3uSD/1690/ , the `width` of the `select` box is `150px`. Yet, when i click the arrow, the menu items are displayed beyond `150 px` because of just one item `"This is my very long string"`.

How can i limit the menu items to fit within 150 px?

Edit: Below is what is shown currently. Notice how the options box slip beyond the width of select box. "This is my very long string" is displayed fully but the options box expands beyond the drop down select box.
[image]

What I require is something like below
[image]

Notice that, although the text is truncated, the options box is still aligned with the combo box

Answer (score 0):

This website has various different methods to solve your problem
[Controlling the width of SELECT lists](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/selectwidth.htm)

I think I found somewhat similar problem on stackoverflow itself. Use of css should resolve your problem
[How can change width of dropdown list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931571/how-can-change-width-of-dropdown-list)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Thank your for your sugggestions

Answer (score 0):

try this code Its working fine.

HTML:-

```
  <select name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr">
  <option value="kg">Kg</option>
  <option value="gm">Gm</option>
  <option value="pound">Pound</option>
  <option value="MetricTon">Metric ton</option>
  <option value="litre">Litre</option>
  <option value="ounce">Ounce</option>
 </select>
```

CSS:-

```
       #wgtmsr{
       width:150px;   
        }

       #wgtmsr option{
         width:100px;   
         }
```

[Check JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4oqcLa9L/)

Comment: when i put a long string in that fiddle demo, the options box takes the width of the long string. but i require it to be fixed

Comment: you cant do this with a standard <option> you will need to roll-your-own or find a menu plugin [Click Here](http://jquery.com)

Comment: I found some sample in GitHub[github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu)