# How to keep Fix width in between two or more li in select option Dropdown?

Tags: php, html, css

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="dynamic-select" >
    <option value=""  style="bold"> </option>
    <option value=""  style="bold">Code&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Name </option>
    <?php
            include "config.php";
            echo $sup_code="select * from supplier where status='active' order BY su_code ASC";
            $sel_sup_code = mysql_query($sup_code) or die(mysql_error());
            while($row_sup_code=mysql_fetch_array($sel_sup_code))
            {
            ?>
               <option value="supplier.php?selectedid=<?php echo $row_sup_code['id']; ?>" >
               <li>&nbsp;&nbsp; <?php echo $row_sup_code['su_code']; ?> </li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<li> <?php echo $row_sup_code['su_name'] ?> </li> 
               </option>
            <?php
            }
           ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931571/how-can-change-width-of-dropdown-list

Comment: i want all option in one line and in fixed width like as code...some space...name...some space...City....like 01  Diamond  New York   or if this is not possible then tell me how i drae a table in dropdown using mysql data

Comment: Why did you use  <li> ? just append values in option tag with space

Comment: but i dont want space between two.....fixed width?...so

Answer (score 0):

The `option` tag is not allowed to have any children, you can either just play around with fake spaces (`&nbsp`) or replace `select` with a `div` then submit data through `javascript`.

---

**Example of spaces:**

```html
<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="dynamic-select">
  <option value=""> </option>
  <option value="" style="font-weight: bold">Code &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Name</option>
  <option value="123">&nbsp;&nbsp; 123 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum</option>
  <option value="345">&nbsp;&nbsp; 345 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum</option>
  <option value="6789">&nbsp;&nbsp; 6789 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum</option>
  <option value="10">&nbsp;&nbsp; 10 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum</option>
</select>
```

As you see, code with varying length causes inconsistencies, therefore you must modify number of spaces **based on length**, for example:

> 0 space before 4 characters code
>
> 1 space before 3 characters code
>
> 2 spaces before 2 characters code
>
> 3 spaces before 1 character code
>
> ```
> Code - Name
>    1 - 1 character
>   22 - 2 characters
>  333 - 3 characters
> 4444 - 4 characters
> ```

**The result will look like this:**

```html
<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="dynamic-select" style="font-family:monospace;">
  <option value=""> </option>
  <option value="" style="font-weight: bold">Code &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Name</option>
  <option value="123">&nbsp;123 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum</option>
  <option value="345">&nbsp;345 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum</option>
  <option value="6789">6789 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum</option>
  <option value="10">&nbsp;&nbsp;10 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum</option>
</select>
```

Please note that to ensure exact spacing, use a **monospace font** for the select (I added `style="font-family:monospace;"`.

To conclude, make your PHP code check for length of product code and then add dynamic space based on that, e.g: `( if length = 4, space = 0 )` etc...

P.S: `style="bold"` should be `style="font-weight: bold;"`.

Comment: Thank you For your Answer Mr. Aziz but i have little Confusion..can you say me or give me a code for  how can i check the length of name and put it &nbsp; from that script automatically because user have no fixed name..some may be 5 character or some may be 40...i hope you Understand my confusion for this dropdown