# Jquery multiselect dropdown list width getting disturb when hide/show dropdown using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am using multiselect jquery dropdown, initially it has display:none; property, on button click i removed the none property  like. $('.abc').show(); But when I doing this dropdown listing width getting lesser than the dropdon width.

please suggest, how can i achieve this.

Js Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click','.add-more', function(){

       $('.abc').show('slow'); 

    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group abc" style="display:none;">
       <label>ABC</label>
        <select autocomplete='off' class="multi" multiple="true" name="abc">
                <option>Apple</option>
                <option>Ball</option>
                <option>Cricket</option>
                <option>Doll</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Create jsfiddle to understand the problem

Comment: Check the link mentioned below
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931571/how-can-change-width-of-dropdown-list

Comment: thanks friends....here I was wrong, I have done little changes, like below   $('.abc').show('slow');  to $('.abc').show(); $('.abc').multiselect("refresh");     and problem solved thats it...