# A responsive dropdown menu doesn't redirect to external sites

Tags: html, css

I have one more question about my website [www.springtribe.de](http://www.springtribe.de) .

I have programmed the small responsive dropdown menu for the mobile site - the problem is that the menu doesn't direct me to the third-party websites even though I have put those third-party links into my HTML.

[For example - You can see the Instagram selected on the right top corner, but my website is stuck with the landing page when it's supposed to be moved onto an Instagram page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2A8F.png)

Here are my HTML and CSS for the problem dropdown menu. Any insights on what might have gone wrong appreciated!

**HTML + CSS**

```css
/* Header */
header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #c6c1c1;
  background-color: white;
}

header .content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.875rem;
}


header .site-logo {
  flex: 1;
  width: 60%
}

header nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  padding-inline-start: 40px;
}

nav li {
  padding-left: 3.5rem;
}

nav li:last-child {
  display: flex;
}

nav a {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #de6cb6;
}

nav select {
  display: none;
}

nav .button {
  padding: .1875rem .5rem;
  background-color: #9dc20b;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: white;
}

a:-webkit-any-link {
  cursor: pointer;
}

header .icon {
  width: 1rem;
  padding-left: .75rem;
  color: #de6cb6
}

header .mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  
  nav li:last-child {
    display: block;
  }

  header .content {
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  header {
    float: none;
  }
  
  header nav ul {
    display: none;
  }

  header nav select {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  

  header .content {
    padding: .5rem 0;
  }


}
```

```html
 <!-- Header -->
  <header>
    <div class="content" style="height: 60px;">
      <a href="landingde.html"  class="site-logo"><img src="./resources/images/cropped_springtribelogo_notagline.png" style="height:60px;"></a>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html">EN</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/springtribe.de/?hl=en"><img class="icon" src="./resources/images/instagram (1.png"></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/florian-zejewski-03653b164/?originalSubdomain=de"><img class="Linkedin" src="./resources/images/Linkedin_saturated_4.png" style="width: 20px; color: #de6cb6; margin-left: 8px;"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <select>
          <option value="/impressum.html/">Impressum</option>
          <option value="/index.html/">EN</option>
          <option value="https://www.instagram.com/springtribe.de/?hl=en">Instagram</option>
          <option value="https://www.linkedin.com/in/florian-zejewski-03653b164/?originalSubdomain=de">Linkedin</option>
        </select>
        </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Without JavaScript, that HTML alone won't do anything

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you need some JavaScript, See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9bd4a7h/) for this working in action.

```html
<select onChange="window.open(this.value)">
<option value ="">select</option> 
<option value="/impressum.html/">Impressum</option>
<option value="/index.html/">EN</option>
<option value="https://www.instagram.com/springtribe.de/?hl=en">Instagram</option>
<option value="https://www.linkedin.com/in/florian-zejewski-03653b164/?originalSubdomain=de">Linkedin</option>
</select>
```

The onchange event fires when a different option is selected. `window.open(url)` opens a new tab with the passed `url`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the codes! Now my dropdown is working perfectly :)

Comment: One more question - would it be possible for me to change the size of the drop down menu? It does display on the mobile but it looks too tiny. I have tried tips listed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931571/how-can-change-width-of-dropdown-list

But it didn't work out for me.

Comment: You can use `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {select {width: 200px;}}`. Define the `width` to whatever you desire. If my answer solved your original issue, please mark it as accepted so the system won't categorise it wrongly.

Comment: @morry239 Did the code in my prev. comment work?

Comment: Thanks for the source code again. I applied it to my VScode and the width of the drop down menu got longer, but the options (imprint, Instagram etc) still displays the tiny text.

Comment: @morry239 `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {select {width: 200px;}option{font-size: 2rem;}}`. This will make the font of the options larger as well.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the text on the dropdown menu "select..." is still tiny after i applied that code. I was able to change the width of the dropdown square but the text in it stayed unchanged.