# How To Fix This "Select" Drop Down Using Css

Tags: html, css, select, drop-down-menu

This text "**Third OMG! How can one option contain soooo many words? This really is a lot of words.**" make my Select box width more than 300px.

```
<form action="" method="get">
<select name="monster-widget-just-testing">
<option value="0">First
</option><option value="1">Second
</option><option value="2">Third OMG! How can one option contain soooo many words? This really is a lot of words.
</option></select>
</form>
```

View the demo in here > http://jsfiddle.net/VHf9r/

How to make the box width box always 300px with that text???

Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think there's a way to adjust the width of the "drop down part" of `select`...

Comment: selects are a b*tch to style. I just wouldn't bother...

Comment: Are you trying to control the width of the drop-down part of the `select` box (as opposed to the part that is always visible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following CSS works in all of the main browsers except for Google Chrome. I don't know about a solution for chrome but yes this works:

```
#myselect { 
width:300px; 
} 
#myselect option { 
width:300px; 
}
```

Just append the `myselect` id to the select element like so:

```
<select id="myselect" name="monster-widget-just-testing">
```

More about this here: [Set width of dropdown element in HTML select dropdown options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702186/set-width-of-dropdown-element-in-html-select-dropdown-options)

Here is a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sVv6x/

To OP: This will not work in Google Chrome, however it does work in Firefox and other browsers (**I have just tested it and it works O.K**)

Comment: Including `option` here probably isn't necessary.

Comment: @v123shine See my edit - Chrome is problematic

Answer (score 0):

Or this one: 
      .widget_text select {
       min-width: 300px;
}

Comment: This set the min width, i think you mean `max-width`

Comment: No I meant min-width Karl.  If you look at the J.S. Fiddle the option list is too narrow so min-width would not allow anything less than 300px. Max-width will not help at all.