# how to change option width in select tag with javascript or css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

How may I change the "option" tag width from select tag?

I need to set the size of the box shown below to be smaller than the width of the "select".

```
<select id="Select" style="width: 120px;">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="5">4</option>
</select>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks likes this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702186/set-width-of-dropdown-element-in-html-select-dropdown-options

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

```
#select option { 
    width:100px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what width are you referencing to, but here is some jQuery since you mentioned it in the tags:

```
${"#Select option"}.something(); //will select all of the options tags in your <select>
${"#Select option:eq(1)"}.something(); // will select an option tag with specified index
 //(1 in the example, index is zero-based)
```

Check the jQuery documentation for the list of available functions. For example, width("100px") will set width of selected elements. Not sure if that's what you're asking.