# How to reduce dropdown box width in the select box

Tags: html, css

I have the select box field with downarrow image.when i have select ,dropdown box width is enlarge then the orginal select box width.

[image]

code :

```
<div id="styled-select">   
    <select name="group" id="group">
        <option val="">Please choose</option>
        <option val="1">Option 1</option>
        <option val="2">Option 2</option>
        <option val="3">Option 3</option>
        <option val="4">Option 4</option>
    </select>   
</div>  

#styled-select {
   width: 260px;
   height: 34px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: url("../img/downarrow_blue.png") no-repeat right #fff;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   margin:auto;
   border-radius:6px;
}
#styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 282px;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 15px;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 34px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   font-family:helvetica-roman;
   color:#9C9C9C;   
}
```

when i have changed   #styled-select select {   width: 260px; } . I got this output in firefox.

[image]

how to reduce dropdown box width is equal to the select box.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702186/set-width-of-dropdown-element-in-html-select-dropdown-options

Comment: @Kennedy Please let me know if my answer worked for you or if you have any issues with the answer. Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.

Comment: @Kennedy I hope you are trying my latest fiddle and not the earlier version. Here's the link again and believe me I personally tested it on FF and Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/9SfJ7/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correction can be done to your css `#styled-select select` on property  `width` . here's the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9SfJ7/2/) for demo

```
#styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 260px;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 15px;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 34px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   font-family:helvetica-roman;
   color:#9C9C9C;   
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
```

**PS:**
Please note that the down arrow showing over your image is a feature of FF and is not expected to be corrected any time soon.

I now realise why you had put the extra width in first place as that is one way to solve for removal of FF down arrow.

Comment: when i have changed width to 260px.I got default arrow in firefox.I had uploaded image in question.

Answer (score 0):

Set the **equal** `width` in both `#styled-select`  and `#styled-select select`

```
   #styled-select {
       width: 260px;
       height: 34px;
       overflow: hidden;
       background: url("../img/downarrow_blue.png") no-repeat right #fff;
       border: 1px solid #ccc;
       margin:auto;
       border-radius:6px;
    }
    #styled-select select {
       background: transparent;
       width: 260px;
       padding: 5px;
       font-size: 15px;
       line-height: 1;
       border: 0;
       border-radius: 0;
       height: 34px;
       -webkit-appearance: none;
       font-family:helvetica-roman;
       color:#9C9C9C;   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change `width:282px` of `#styled-select select` in to same value `width:260px` of parent `#styled-select`..

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/6aPUh/1/

```
#styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 260px;/*change here*/
   padding: 5px 0;
   font-size: 15px;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 34px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   font-family:helvetica-roman;
   color:#9C9C9C;   
}
```