# How to make <option> wider than <select> in IE6?

Tags: css, html-select, internet-explorer-6

The `<select>` has a width of `60px`,

but the content of `<option>` is longer than that.

Which is hidden in IE6.

[image]

How to fix that?

Comment: Duplicate?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700807/how-to-show-extended-option-in-select-list, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702186/set-width-of-dropdown-element-in-html-select-dropdown-options

Comment: @anddoutoi,watched through those threads,seems no solution.

Comment: @Jason - IE7 has the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to figure this out before and all I could find were javascript hacks. I found one once upon a time that worked well but I don't know where.

You could try this:
http://brandonbuttars.com/2009/09/css-select-options-internet-explorer-cut-off/

Or plenty of other options on Google:
http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=ie6+cutoff+select+options&btnG=Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=

Answer (score 0):

We added a button next to select which change select's width to default value, so it becomes non-limited in width.

Answer (score 0):

Short and easy answer: it´s not possible without JavaScript. And with the JavaScript-solution your layout will *jump* when the `select` gets wider.

See my comment on duplicate threads for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible. You could use custom scripts like this one: http://www.icant.co.uk/forreview/tamingselect/, but still - it is JavaScript based solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is years later but it may help someone searching for a solution.

You can do it in CSS by setting the select's width when it is in focus, e.g.

```
select {
    width: 100px; /* normal state */
}
```

and

```
select:focus {
    width: 200px; /* wider when in focus */
}
```

Full article at http://dinowebs.net/?p=114