# Customize select dropdown with CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I have to display `<select>` with 100px size, but the `<option>` in it are much longer and I want to display entire content, so I wrapped `<select>` with a `<div>` and set the size to 100px. I have used an background image for the dropdown arrow. My problem is, as you can see in the below link, the text is overlapping the image. How to make the text not overlap on the image?

I don't want to use any plugins.

http://jsfiddle.net/JavaKB/hf5CV/8/

Comment: would appreciate if you tell me why you are giving negative vote.

Comment: Ignore them, I get that a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in stead of applying the background image to the div, you could use a `:after` pseudo element, apply the background image to that, and position it on top of the select.

It would look something like this:

```
.styled-select {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.styled-select:after {
    content: '';
     background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNROu.jpg") no-repeat right;
    width: 20px;
    height: 18px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Note that I added the `pointer-events: none;` to make sure the click still triggers the select when you click on the arrow image. It might not be fully cross browser compatible, you might have to do some research on that...

I updated your fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/hf5CV/24/

Comment: Accepting this, as this is the closest possible solution, as you said, does not work on IE 8. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Give a `width: 100px` to your select input.

```
.styled-select select {
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: This. I'd also add that you don't need the width on `.styled-select` after you adjust it on `.styled-select select`

Comment: If I give 100px width to select tag, as the options are too long, would not display complete content.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, which would fit me better.

http://www.dougboude.com/blog/1/2008/05/Viewing-Option-Text-in-IE7-thats-Wider-than-the-Select-List.cfm

From here:

[Recommendations for dropdown menu items that are too wide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586718/recommendations-for-dropdown-menu-items-that-are-too-wide)